# Boto - S3 client put with Invalid ARN: Unrecognized format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I use boto3 to write data in S3 (**other AWS account**)

```
s3.put_object(Body=open("/tmp/file.csv", "rb"), Bucket="arn:aws:s3:eu-west-1:123456789123:foo-bar-staging", Key="foo_barr/to_process/1234.csv", ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')
```

I have this error:

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid ARN: Unrecognized format: arn:aws:s3:eu-west-1:123456789123:foo-bar-staging (type: foo-bar-staging)
```

AWS official doc (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html)

**Bucket (string) -- [REQUIRED]**

The bucket name to which the PUT action was initiated.

When using this action with an access point, you must direct requests to the access point hostname. The access point hostname takes the form `AccessPointName-AccountId.s3-accesspoint.Region.amazonaws.com`. When using this action with an access point through the Amazon Web Services SDKs, you provide the access point ARN in place of the bucket name. For more information about access point ARNs, see Using access points in the Amazon S3 User Guide.

When using this action with Amazon S3 on Outposts, you must direct requests to the S3 on Outposts hostname. The S3 on Outposts hostname takes the form `AccessPointName-AccountId.outpostID.s3-outposts.Region.amazonaws.com`. When using this action with S3 on Outposts through the Amazon Web Services SDKs, you provide the Outposts bucket ARN in place of the bucket name. For more information about S3 on Outposts ARNs, see Using Amazon S3 on Outposts in the Amazon S3 User Guide .

Comment: is this the correct access point ARN? did you see Using access points in the Amazon S3 User Guide ? no you did not.

Comment: @user253751, yes is correct access point ARN. Yes, I use access points in the Amazon S3 User Guide

Comment: [Using access points in the Amazon S3 User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-access-points.html). I know you did not see this because the 4th line on the page tells you what access point ARNs look like, and this is not one.

Comment: I think bucket names are globally unique - so just specify the bucket name itself, not the arn

Answer (score 0):

The access point ARN's format should actually include the text "accesspoint/" and then you add your resource name, [like this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-access-points.html):

```
arn:aws:s3:region:account-id:accesspoint/resource
```